# Unable to load DLL 'Yubico.NativeShims' when trying to use Yubico SDK in .NET

Tags: dll, yubico

I am trying to extract the X509 certificate off of my Yubikey's PIV programmatically. I am using .NET Standard 2.0 on Windows 10, and I am trying to install and use the Yubico SDK Nuget package (Yubico.Yubikey 1.3.1). After installing the package and making sure the DLLs are being copied to my bin directory, I am running my application and trying to run the example code from the SDK User Guide

The first line of the example code is: `Dim yubikey = YubiKeyDevice.FindAll().First` -- however on executing this first line I am getting an exception about a DLL that cannot be loaded.

```
System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'Yubico.NativeShims': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'
```

Sure enough, there is no Yubikey.NativeShims DLL being copied to my bin directory (although I do have a Yubico.Core.dll, a Yubico.Yubikey.dll, and a Yubico.DotNetPolyfills.dll).  Even after tracking down a copy of this missing DLL for my target platform, and putting it in the bin folder, I still get this exception.

What am I missing?

I have included the complete stack trace from the exception here:

```
   at Yubico.PlatformInterop.NativeMethods.SCardEstablishContext(SCARD_SCOPE scope, SCardContext& context)
   at Yubico.Core.Devices.SmartCard.DesktopSmartCardDeviceListener..ctor()
   at Yubico.Core.Devices.SmartCard.SmartCardDeviceListener.Create()
   at Yubico.YubiKey.YubiKeyDeviceListener..ctor()
   at Yubico.YubiKey.YubiKeyDeviceListener.<>c.<.cctor>b__34_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Yubico.YubiKey.YubiKeyDeviceListener.get_Instance()
   at Yubico.YubiKey.YubiKeyDevice.FindByTransport(Transport transport)
   at Yubico.YubiKey.YubiKeyDevice.FindAll()
   at ClassLibrary1.Class1.Work() in C:\Users\jzylkin\source\repos\WindowsApp3\ClassLibrary1\Class1.vb:line 6
   at WindowsApp3.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\jzylkin\source\repos\WindowsApp3\WindowsApp3\Form1.vb:line 6
   at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Here is the vbproj project

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>ClassLibrary1</RootNamespace>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>True</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Yubico.YubiKey" Version="1.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Jack,

I pumped in the similar problem.
I just renamed Yubico.NativeShims.dll to Yubico.NativeShims (just remove .dll extension) and it worked.

Sharon